# Django: Get joined data from from filter

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following, table / class:

```
 Class UserFriend(model.Model):
      user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='friend_users' )
      friend = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='friend_friends')
```

where User is the built-in auth_user class, I want to get only the friends, not the userfriends object.

I'm doing the following:

```
 friends = user.friend_users.filter(hide=False).order_by('friend__first_name')
```

How can I get just the friend item from this, not the userfriend.  The only thing I can think of is using a for loop, but is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
friends = User.objects.filter(friend_friends__user=user, 
                              friend_friends__hide=False)
```

That is, you want to find all users for which there is `UserFriend` entry where the friend points to them, and the user points to `user`.

Comment: I was going in the wrong direction.  Thanks a bunch!